# Why is the fourth nested value way slower to access than the fifth?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was building a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/n-level-object-nesting) to illustrate time it took to access nested object members and I found this strange phenomenon. For some reason, the test run drastically slower for the fourth-nested object member than the fifth. I've tried this in Chrome and Firefox and am getting the same results.

[image]

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object is this, my comment added:

```
var obj = {
  "one": {
    "two": {
      "three": {
        "four": {
          "five": {
            "value": 0
          }
          /* MISSING "value": 0 */
        },
        "value": 0
      },
      "value": 0
    },
    "value": 0
  },
  "value": 0
};
```

};

The object at the `"four"` key doesn't have a `"value"` key, however, so apparently the JavaScript engine(s) have to do extra work to handle that case: miss the key look-up on the object, miss the key look-up on the object's prototype `Object`, return `undefined`, and then compute `NaN` when you add `1` to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `obj.one.two.three.four` does not have a `value` attribute. In that one case, JavaScript traverses the prototype chain looking for the missing attribute before finally assigning `NaN` to `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your test. You didn't have a value field for 'four'. I also added a write process to the test to get better values;
[here you got the fixed jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/n-level-object-nesting/4)